# Comment System CSS text gets out of box

Tags: php, css

I have recently coded a simple comment system using PHP.

http://runescapepvp.net/jony/index.php

As you see in the following link I posted, if the comment is long, it will get out of the box.
Im not to sure why it happens when I've set max width for text.

Im using this to call the boxes

```
function showComments() {
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `comments` ORDER BY `comment_id` DESC LIMIT 5") or die (mysql_error());
    $allcomments = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `comments` ORDER BY `comment_id`") or die (mysql_error());
    if (mysql_num_rows($query) == 0) {
        echo '<br /><br />';
        handleAlerts("noComments");
    } else {
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
            echo "
            <br />
            <br />
            <div class='comments'>
                <div class='title'><span class='author'>Posted by: ".$row['comment_guest']."</span><span class='date'>At ".$row['comment_time'].", ".$row['comment_date']."</span></div>
                <div class='comment'>
                    <span class='message'>
                    ".$row['comment']."
                    </span>
                    <br />
                    <a href='index.php?delete=comment&id=".$row['comment_id']."'><div class='button_delete'>Delete</div></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            ";
        }
    }
        echo '<br /><br /><br />';
}
```

CSS:

```
.title {
background-image: url("../img/header.png"); background-repeat: repeat-x;
width: 100%;
height: 56px;
border: solid 1px #a8a8a8;
line-height: 56px;
font-size: 17px;
color: grey;
text-align: left;
display: block;
}

.comments {
position: relative;
top: 50px;
}


.comment {
width: 640px;
height: auto;
display: block;
min-height: 100px;
background-color: #e6e6e6;
border-left: solid 1px #a8a8a8;
border-right: solid 1px #a8a8a8;
border-bottom: solid 1px #a8a8a8;
}

.message {
width: 600px;
display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
padding-top: 10px;
}
```

Why is it happening? 
I am not really sure if the error is related to PHP.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this in css:

To hide what is not part of the box:

```
.comment {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

To use the new css3 property to break the long word:

```
.comment {
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

Comment: But this won't work on all web browsers, right?
Overflow just hides it, I want it to work as word-break: break-all; it's awesome, but is there any other ways to do it with older CSS versions?

Comment: @purepksorpurepk Support is pretty good: http://caniuse.com/#search=word-wrap. An alternative (and ugly...) solution would be to use `wordwrap` in php: http://php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php

Comment: Thanks, the PHP didn't work, but the support seems pretty good as you said. I decided to use that ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can try adding this CSS to your `.comment` class:

```
word-break: break-all;
```

Or

```
overflow: auto;
```